# Sign In with Apple - Sign-Up not completed. dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sign-in-with-apple

I trying to make a .net core 3.1 web app, using "Sign in with apple", I have followed just about every sample I can find, but I keep getting "Sign-up not Completed"

I have tried to cook every think down, but I can't find the missing setting/implementation.

I suspect something with the Return URLs, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use url encoding (%20 for spaces) when specifying response type?

eg: the URL should be like this : 
.../authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=&response_type=**code%20id_token**&scope=**name%20email**&response_mode=form_post&state=&nonce=

Comment: I’ve seen the answer other place, but not sure that I’m using spaces! Where is this url used?

Comment: If you are using Sign in with Apple JS on your web page, in your web browser right click the sign in with apple button and inspect it, and see the value generated in <a href="....">

Comment: I have used this sample https://github.com/martincostello/SignInWithAppleSample